# Boolean Algebra - How to Simplify

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Working in JS and just started learning about boolean algebra. Wondering if there is a way to simplify this expression:

(!variableOne || !variableTwo)

I recall hearing something about how two 'nots' means you can change the sign, but I'm not seeing much about this when I google 'boolean algebra'.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: Just for fun: `variableOne<=!variableTwo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
!(a && b) = !a || !b 
!(a || b) = !a && !b
```

In your case it is

```
!(variableOne && variableTwo)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [De'Morgans Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) says, you can transform `!a || !b` in `!(a && b)`

so you can have `!(variableOne && variableTwo)`

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but to put further explanation:

> - The negation of an **and** statement is logically equivalent to the **or** statement in which each component is negated.

**Symbolically:**
`!(A && B) = !A || !B`

> - The negation of an **or** statement is logically equivalent to the **and** statement in which each component is negated.

**Symbolically:**
 `!(A || B) = !A && !B`

In your case you had used `!variableOne || !variableTwo` so it's equivalent to the first Law `!(variableOne && variableTwo) == !variableOne || !variableTwo`.